# Why cant i connect to my server from non local networks

Tags: python, sockets, networking, ip

server:

```
port = 55000
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind(('', port))
server_socket.listen(5)
while True:
ready_to_read, ready_to_write, in_error = select.select(socket_list, [], [], 0)
for sock in ready_to_read:
    if sock == server_socket:
        connect, addr = server_socket.accept()
        socket_list.append(connect)
        connect.send(("You are connected from:" + str(addr)).encode())
```

client:

```
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
port = 55000           
client_socket.connect(('109.65.63.141', port))
isConnected_msg = client_socket.recv(1024)
print(isConnected_msg.decode())
```

there is more code in the server and the client but its irrelevant i believe.

if im using '127.0.0.1' everything works, if im using my public ip im getting the error:
[image]

im trying to make an online chatting app, i have done a lot of reading online and i think i understand the problem, however i dont know to fix it. the ip in client's script is my router's public ip address, from my understanding i have to somehow "tell" the router to navigate the client request to my specific device (computer) eg 10.0.0.10 and then it would work? please help.

Answer (score 0):

The task of "telling the router to navigate the client request to [your] specific device" is called *port forwarding* and yes it is probably the cause of the problem. How to enable port forwarding on your router is totally dependend of your router. Most home routers have according settings in the web GUI and you will probably find instructions when explicitly searching for your router model.

Another issue that may arise if you enabled port forwarding correctly on your router is that the Windows firewall may block the request, so you have to make sure to configure it correctly as well.

**This beeing said, a word of warning:**
Opening a port on the router and opening a hole in the firewall makes your computer a potential target for malware attacks. I would **strongly not recommend** doing that just for learning how to code a chat program. Try to develop your app (server and client) on your local host and wait until you learned enough to know, how and when to open a port to the wide and dangerous internet.